# Как повторить анимацию по ховере на картинку?

Tags: html, css

как вот тут http://ubc-build.com.ua/gallery/gallery_2/tm_pg_album/green-hills/

```css
.portfolio__wrap {
  display: flex;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.portfolio__item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 400px;
  transition-delay: .05s;
}

.portfolio__item:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s background-color;
}

.portfolio__item:hover img {
  filter: none;
}

.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__label,
.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__title,
.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__desc {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__icon {
  animation: animationInFrames linear 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio__image {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.portfolio__image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 0.3s filter;
}

.portfolio__block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 20px;
}

.portfolio__icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: animationOutFrames linear 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation-delay: .15s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.portfolio__label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #68bec4;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.portfolio__title {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.portfolio__title,
.portfolio__desc {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 0.3s opacity, 0.3s transform;
}

@keyframes animationOutFrames {

  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  20% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }

  40% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }

  60% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

}

@keyframes animationInFrames {

  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  20% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }

  40% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }

  60% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

}


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__wrap">
            <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
                <div class="portfolio__image">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nRwc8fk/britanskij-oftal-mologicheskij-centr-26-400x300.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio__block">
                    <p class="portfolio__label">Album</p>
                    <div class="portfolio__icon">
                        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/124/124016.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class="portfolio__title">title 1</p>
                    <p class="portfolio__desc">desc 1</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="portfolio__item">
                <div class="portfolio__image">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/YbgHqf9/Green-Hills-018-400x300.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio__block">
                    <p class="portfolio__label">Album</p>
                    <div class="portfolio__icon">
                        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/124/124016.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class="portfolio__title">title 1</p>
                    <p class="portfolio__desc">desc 1</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: сдвинуть слево как именно?

Comment: спасибо, но по ховеру еще там будто какая то полоса пробегает еще. Это что? возможно, повторить?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BaWRXKQ - вот смотри

Comment: эффект готовый полностью, вопрос решён ?

Comment: да, спасибо огромное)